# Cost_Matrix Distance: Vehicle routing problem!

Tags: qgis, pgrouting, osm2pgsql

I'd like to calculate the "real distance" between **one source** and **many targets**, such as we do in the "vehicle routing problem", in order to get the matrix distance at the end.

after using the osm2po, and loading the topology into QGIS, and installing pgrouting plugin:

How could I do this cost matrix with the Pgrouting/QGIS? to get a result such as in like in 
points are {1,2,3}, the problem is asymetric

1---1=0
1---2=2
1---3=4
2---1=5
2---2=0
2---3=21
3---1=5
3---2=4
3---3=0

knowing that almost the functions found in Pgrouting are for calculating the shortest paths, and the function "tsp_euclid" doesn't return a result in my case.